Semantic MediaWiki further results / pagination errors out
I have a Semantic MediaWiki query that will return several hundred results. This query has a ... further results link at the bottom of the table. Clicking this link gives an error page:

Internal Error - Fatal exception of type "Error"

I looked at the exception logs and the error there is a bit more descriptive:

Error: Typed property Parser::$mOutput must not be accessed before initialization

This error is only happening with that "further results" link. Increasing the limit to a large enough number to include all results on a single page works just fine.
Sample query:
{{#ask: 
[[Category:SampleCategory]]
 | ?SampleProperty
 | mainlabel=Title
 | format=table
 | limit=5
}}

I am using Semantic MediaWiki 4.1.3 and MediaWiki 1.41.1.


I am using Semantic MediaWiki 4.1.3 and MediaWiki 1.41.1.

Semantic MediaWiki 4.1.x works only with MediaWiki 1.35.0 up to 1.39.x.
For MediaWiki 1.41.x use Semantic MediaWiki 4.2.x
See the compatibility matrix: https://github.com/SemanticMediaWiki/SemanticMediaWiki/blob/master/docs/COMPATIBILITY.md
